# PyEpics camonitor() shall only return the value of a PV with specific format

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My goal is to display the value of an epics PV with a Tkinter Label that is automatically updated when the PV value changes.
For this I wanted to make use of camonitor() as shown in the example below.
However, camonitor() returns also the PV name and timestamp and the PV value is not in the format I would like (precision, rounding, etc.).
Here a code example of my approach:

```
import tkinter as tk
from epics import camonitor

display = tk.Tk()    
sv = tk.StringVar()
l = tk.Label(display, textvariable = sv)
l.place()
camonitor('pvname', writer=sv.set)
display.mainloop()
```

I could of course obtain just the PV value by cutting the last part of the string camonitor() returns, but it would create a lot of overhead in the code, especially if I would like to do this for many more PVs. And I can also not obtain the desired format like that.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by ***it would create a lot of overhead in the code***? String manipulation is not costly.

Comment: I mean that the code would become cluttered. To manipulate the string, I would create a new function that gets the string from the writer of camonitor(). As the function needs to assign the extracted string (value) to a specific StringVar (sv in my code example), I need to create such a function for every PV I want to monitor! I would have thought there is a neater way.

Comment: According to the official document on [camonitor()](https://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/pyepics3/overview.html#camonitor), it is more flexible to pass a function using the `callback` option.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the documentation again as suggested by acw1668, I now just create a single line callback funtion for each PV I want to read back.
For future reference to anyone:

```
import tkinter as tk
from epics import camonitor

# one callback function per PV to be monitored:
def cb1(value=None,**kw): [sv1.set(str(value))]

display = tk.Tk()    
sv1 = tk.StringVar()
l1 = tk.Label(display, textvariable = sv1)
l1.place()
camonitor('pvname1', callback=cb1)

display.mainloop()
```

This is an acceptable solution for me. The problem with the formatting is also solved like this.